# Join two tables where right table contains ID's and child ID's without duplicates

Tags: mysql

If I have the following entries in Table A:

```
| Cart| X_ID| Y_ID|
|-----------------|
|  1  |  1  | NULL|
|  2  |  1  |  1  |
|  3  |  1  |  2  |
|  4  |  2  | NULL|
|  5  |  2  |  2  |
```

And I have Table B:

```
| xid | xstr| yid | ystr|
|-----------------------|
|  1  |Apple|  1  | Seed|
|  1  |Apple|  2  | Stem|
|  2  | Rock|  1  | Red |
|  2  | Rock|  2  | Blue|
```

What I need:

```
| Cart| X_ID| xstr| Y_ID| ystr|
|-----------------------------|
|  1  |  1  |Apple| NULL| NULL|
|  2  |  1  |Apple|  1  | Seed|
|  3  |  1  |Apple|  2  | Stem|
|  4  |  2  | Rock| NULL| NULL|
|  5  |  2  | Rock|  2  | Blue|
```

I have something that works pretty well right now, but I think it's inefficient.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.Cart, 
    A.X_ID, 
    ISNULL(B2.xstr, '') AS xstr
    A.Y_ID, 
    ISNULL(B3.ystr, '') AS ystr
FROM
    A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tmp.xid, tmp.xstr FROM B AS tmp) AS B2
        ON A.X_ID = B2.xid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tmp.yid, tmp.ystr FROM B AS tmp) AS B3
        ON A.Y_ID = B2.yid
```

Is there an easier way of doing this? I have to do this for a bunch of "ID's"

I just realized that this doesn't account for Y dependent of X. Ideally, I want to check if X != null, y(x)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is this:

```
SELECT
  A.Cart,
  A.X_ID,
  COALESCE(X.xstr, '') AS xstr,
  A.Y_ID,
  COALESCE(Y.xstr, '') AS ystr,
  ..
FROM
  A LEFT JOIN B AS X ON A.X_ID = B.xid
  LEFT JOIN B AS Y ON A.Y_ID = B.yid
GROUP BY
  A.Cart,
  A.X_ID,
  A.Y_ID
```

it is often not considered a good practice to GROUP BY a few fields and SELECT non aggregated columns at the same time, please see [how MySQL handles group by queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html), but on this context it should be perfectly fine.

I would suggest you, if possible, to use a normalized database structure.